# Filtering based on ccRecipients, bccRecipients, toRecipients in Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I want to filter email when **ccRecipients** or **bccRecipients** or **toRecipients** contains given email id.

**Here is my request:**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2021-09-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2021-12-15 and toRecipients/emailAddress/any(s:s eq 'something@email.com')`

Response to this request:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-28T17:57:06",
            "request-id": "some-client-id",
            "client-request-id": "something-client-request-id"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way where we can filter emails if **ccRecipients** or **bccRecipients** or **toRecipients** contains given email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter based on those properties because they don't support filtering, you can use them in a search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-query-parameter

so

```
/me/messages?$search="to:blah@blah.com"&$select=subject,toRecipients
```

or you could use participants which include from,to,cc

```
/me/messages?$search="participants:blah@blah.com"
```